# Mongoose Unique field error message handling

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack

I have a problem with Unique field in Mongoose

It works when i try to create a new user with an existing email or username.

Now it sends always error 500.

but Is there anyway to handle error message efficiently ? For exemple says (Email already exist ou Username already exist) ?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    email : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type : String, required: true},
    userid: {type : String},
    username: {type : String, required: true, unique: true},

})

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
userSchema.index({ '$**': 'text' })

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and the node controllers :

```
exports.createUser = (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10).then(
    (hash) => {
      const user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash,
        userid:req.body.userid,
    username:req.body.username,

      });
      user.save().then(
        () => {
          res.status(201).json({
            message: 'User added successfully!'
          });
        }
      ).catch(
        (error) => {
          res.status(500).json({
            error: error
          });
        }
      );
    }
  );
};
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if email or username is used at the beginning of your code, and send a 400-BadRequest with your custom message like this:

```
exports.createUser =  async (req, res, next) => {

    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) return res.status(400).send("Email already exists");

    user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username});
    if (user) return res.status(400).send("Username already exists.");
    ...
```

Please note that I put async, to be able to use await.

Also I would advise you to use async/await instead of then catch blocks to get rid of callback hell. Your code can be written like this with async/await:

```
exports.createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password, userId, username } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) return res.status(400).json({ error: "Email already exists" });

    user = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (user) return res.status(400).send({ error: "Username already exists" });

    user = new User({ email, password, userId, username });
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: "User added successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Every think it`s just done, just in front handle the error witch you send as response witch status 500 in catch, it will be like this:
{driver: true, name: "MongoError", index: 0, code: 11000, keyPattern: {…}, …}
code: 11000
driver: true
index: 0
keyPattern:
email: 1
**proto**: Object
keyValue:
email: "gjhk@ex.com"
**proto**: Object
name: "MongoError"
**proto**: Object}

Example handle in react:

```
register = async (name, lastName, email, password, cb) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ name, lastName, email, password })
        })
        const result = await res.json()
        if (result.code === 11000) {
            cb(11000)
        }

        if (res.status === 201) {
            localStorage.setItem('authenticated', true)
            localStorage.setItem('userName', result.user.name)
            localStorage.setItem('userLastName', result.user.lastName)
            localStorage.setItem('token', result.token)
            cb()
        } else {
            cb(400)
        }
    } catch{
        cb('Błąd serwera')
    }
}
```

So sorry for the quality of the response, it is my firs comment in English.